# How to use IPython %sql magic to work on a local dataset?

Tags: sql, ipython

Can I use %sql to a dataset I create locally in Ipython notebook? I tried the code below but it didn't work.

```
import pandas as pd
%load_ext sql
test = pd.DataFrame({'x1':[1,2,3,4,5], 'x2': [3,5,2,7,8]})
```

In the next new cell:

```
%%sql 
select * from test where x1 > 3;
```

Comment: DataFrames are not SQL databases, so this won't work.  Read up on Pandas; you can do what you want pretty easily, just not using SQL.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to use SQL on the pandas data frame. I built a database locally and can use %sql to query data from that database.